# Converting a text file to python dictionary - one key and multiple values - with exclusion of one field

Tags: python

I have the following tab-delimited text file:

```
1 John 27 doctor Chicago
2 Nick 33 engineer Washington
```

I am trying to convert it into a python dictionary where the key is the NAME and the age, career and address are the values. I would like to exclude the rankings (1, 2).

Code:

```
myfile = open ("filename", "r") 
d = { } 
for line in myfile: 
    x = line.strip().split("\t") 
    key, values = int(x[0]), x[1:] 
    d.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)
print(d)
```

Comment: Better start by writing some code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is what i tried...myfile = open ("filename", "r")
d = { }
for line in myfile:
    x = line.strip().split("\t")
    key, values = int(x[0]), x[1:]
    d.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)
print(d)

Comment: @SayedSabry: it is better to edit the question and add the code that you tried to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't explain what difficulties you face.
However, from that sample of tab-delimited text, and you want to have dict like:

```
{'John': ['27', 'doctor', 'Chicago'], 'Nick': ['33', 'engineer', 'Washington']}
```

If that's the output you want to reach, then I modified your code a bit.

```
myfile = open ("filename", "r") 
d = { } 
for line in myfile: 
    x = line.strip().split("\t") 
    key, values = x[1], x[2:] 
    d.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a dict indexed by name with values in tuples instead:

```
d = {}
with open('filename', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        _, name, *values = line.strip().split("\t")
        d[name] = values
print(d)
```

With your sample input, this will output:

```
{'John': ('27', 'doctor', 'Chicago'), 'Nick': ('33', 'engineer', 'Washington')}
```